# Are tables in Specflow tied to Step Definitions or the Feature File?

Tags: c#, .net, automated-tests, cucumber, specflow

I looked through the documentation of both Specflow and Cucumber and I couldn't find a definitive answer to this question. Let's say for example I have a [Given] step with a table full of inputs like this :

```
Given I login with a <pin> and it is a valid <user role>
| PIN    | User Role |
| 111111 | Admin     |
| 222222 | User      |
```

My primary question is that if I reuse this step in other feature files do I have to recopy the table with each use or does the table travel with the globally accessed Step Definition?

I am designing the Specflow solution for my company from the ground up and I am trying to stick to DRY as much as possible. So laying a foundation of reusable shared steps is a high priority goal for me. I might be overthinking this question to where I can't see the forest because of the trees, but I like to have these kind of specifics laid out in plain language because it helps me learn better. So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to copy if you using exactly the same step in another feature file. The same step definition is global across your feature file hence the data as well. Each step should be exactly same. If you change even a single letter in your step then you have to generate another step definition.

Comment: Okay, great. That answers my question. I am trying to make a login table of all the potential user roles I can test and I wanted to store it in a SharedUtilities Feature file so I have a central location of all the data to make maintenance easier. I know it's not STRICTLY BDD, but it makes sense to me from an organizational stand point.

Comment: Cool. Thank you :)